# Will the current travel through the 4 ohms lamps if a resistor is put there?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

[image]

This is a part of a question I was solving, the question asked about what will happen if the switch is in position 2.

My answer was to say that all the lamps are going to turn on as I thought the current will travel the way I drew in the picture.

I knew later, though, that my answer was wrong and that the current will only flow through the 12 ohms lamps and then straight to the battery. I thought the reason I was wrong is because, at point x, the current would "prefer" to take the route which has no resistors and go straight to the battery than to take the route with the two 4 ohms resistors.

However someone told me my answer is wrong because of this:

> Current only flows from a higher voltage to a lower voltage. What you highlighted cannot happen because current cannot flow towards a lamp unless there is a lower voltage on the other side of it. The current will continue to the lower voltage of the battery instead.

But I wasn't convinced and to know which of us is right I want to know what will happen if we put a resistor here. Will the current still not travel to the 4 ohms lamp?
[image]

Comment: The bottom diagram will only make the 12 ohm lights dimmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we say "current will flow" and "current won't flow" we are using phrasings which let us simplify the circuit.  By using logic we can deduce that current will not flow through the 4 ohm lamps.

However, if we are not so sure, we can just calculate.  We can assume some current $i$ goes through the 4 ohm lamps, and solve the equations.  If it turns out that $i$ equals zero, that just meant that current didn't' flow through those lamps.

In this case, we can use the equation for serial resistors to find the resistence of the loop through the two 4 ohm lamps: 4ohm + 4ohm = 8ohm.  Thus we have an 8 ohm resistance with those two lamps put together.  Since they are resistive loads, we can use $I=\frac{\Delta V}{R}$ to determine how much current flows through them.

Since they're attached to the same wire, the voltage difference between them is 0V.  Thus, the current is $I=\frac{0V}{8\Omega} = 0 \text A$.  That is to say, the current through that loop is 0.

Which is the same as you would get if you said "no current flows through the 4 ohm lamps," only I was able to calculate this directly rather than using logic.  I calculated the current through the lamps, and found it was 0 amps.  So if you're ever unsure about whether current is flowing through a loop, you can always test it by calculating in these ways.

In later courses, you will find this thinking is useful because you'll start to deal with non-ideal wires, with parasitic capacitance and inductance.  All sorts of interesting stuff can happen at high frequencies, like a disconnected stub of wire can disrupt a signal.  If you remember that you can always just calculate the currents through the wires, and show that they are zero, you won't have to remember all the rules of current flow perfectly.  Then you can focus on the rules which are most useful

*Rules like "always take off your wedding ring when working on a car."  Your ring is a non-ideal wire, and shorting a car battery across that non-ideal wire can get hot in a jiffy!*

Comment: Your answer is totally amazing but I have one question. Why did you decide that the two 4 ohms lamps are connected in series? They look like they are connected in parallel to me.

Comment: @Manar If you were to think of them as in parallel, then the current would have to flow through the top of the lamps (and node 3 on the switch).  In that case, the current could go through both, in the same direction -- the definition of parallel.  However, no current can get out through the top, so the current has to be routing "up" one lamp and "down" the other, in series.

Comment: To brute force the calculations even more, you could use [Kirchhoff's voltage law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_voltage_law) and calculate the current through each lamp individually, without concern as to whether they are in series or parallel.  You would simply assign a direction for the current through each, either in the same direction or in different directions, and if you got the direction of current wrong, you'd get a negative current.

Comment: The only disadvantage to using Kirchhoff's laws to solve every circuit is that you can end up with a pesky large number of simultaneous equations to solve, when all your friends in class are simplifying the circuit to save time on the test.

Answer (score 1):

No, adding a resistor there won't cause the 4 ohm lamps to light up. You need a potential difference across the lamps. One way to achieve that is to move your resistor so that it's between the two 4 ohm lamps.

In these introductory problems, we normally assume that the wires are ideal, with zero resistance. (And we ignore the internal resistance of the battery and assume it's a perfectly stable voltage source, capable of delivering any current). In reality, wires do have some resistance, but it *is* small, on the order of a milliohm or less for a small circuit using copper wire.

You should try calculating the current through those 4 ohm lamps with a 1 milliohm resistance between them, that is, you have 1 milliohm in parallel with 8 ohms.